# Label will not update with the flow

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, label, logic

I am working on this RPSGUI; everything works swell as far as logic is conserned, but I moved onto the final stage about a week or so ago and I have been stuck here every since.  I cannot get my labels to update. So say the user won, the counter would go from 0 to 1, 2 etc. I have a lot of stuff commented out so you can see I have tried.  I actually deleted several portions of what I was commenting out because I was getting confused, but yeah.  I would also like for the gui to say what was played and am unsure about where to even begin with that :-/.  I'm hoping someone could help me with this.  It would mean a lot to me.

Here is the program without the driver class.  Nothing is in the driver class aside making it display.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
    private JButton rockButton, paperButton, scissorsButton;
    private JLabel userLabel, computerLabel, resultLabel, winLabel, tieLabel, loseLabel;
    private int winInt, tieInt, loseInt = 0;
    private String rockButtonText = "Rock";
    private String paperButtonText = "Paper";
    private String scissorsButtonText = "Scissors";
    private JPanel buttonPanel, labelPanel, resultPanel;
    public int computerInt;

    String[] attackArray = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};

    public GamePanel(){
        String[] attackArray = {"Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"};

        setLayout(new  GridLayout(5,3));

        setBackground(Color.white.brighter());
        setForeground(Color.ORANGE.darker());

        //make the buttons
        JButton rockButton = new JButton(rockButtonText);
        JButton paperButton = new JButton(paperButtonText);
        JButton scissorsButton = new JButton(scissorsButtonText);

        //style the buttons
        rockButton.setBackground(Color.orange);
        rockButton.setForeground(Color.black.darker());
        paperButton.setBackground(Color.orange);
        paperButton.setForeground(Color.black.darker());
        scissorsButton.setBackground(Color.orange);
        scissorsButton.setForeground(Color.black.darker());

        //add labels
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User:");
        JLabel computerLabel = new JLabel("Computer:");
        JLabel winLabel = new JLabel("Win: " + winInt);
        JLabel tieLabel = new JLabel("Tie: " + tieInt);
        JLabel loseLabel = new JLabel("Lose:" + loseInt);

        //style Labels
        userLabel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        userLabel.setForeground(Color.black.darker());
        computerLabel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        computerLabel.setForeground(Color.black.darker());      
        winLabel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        winLabel.setForeground(Color.black.darker());       
        tieLabel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        tieLabel.setForeground(Color.black.darker());       
        loseLabel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        loseLabel.setForeground(Color.black.darker());


        //add buttons to panel
        add(rockButton);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));
        add(paperButton);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));
        add(scissorsButton);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));


        add(userLabel);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));
        add(computerLabel);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));


        add(winLabel);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));
        add(tieLabel);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));
        add(loseLabel);
        //add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension (0,10)));


        // add action listeners
        rockButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        paperButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        scissorsButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());


    }
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            int computerSourceAI = (int) (Math.random() * 2); //random generator

                     String oppChoice = attackArray[computerSourceAI];  // the choice of your opponent 

                    String yourChoice = ((JButton) ae.getSource()).getText();  // casts source from object to button and gets the text



               int outcome = determineWinner(yourChoice, oppChoice);

               // 0 = tie
               //1 == win
               //2 = lose

            if (outcome == 1) 
        {

        // win message 
        //System.out.println("You win!");
        winLabel.setText("You Won" + winInt++);
        }

    else if (outcome == 0)
     {

       // tie message
       //System.out.println("Tie");
         tieLabel.setText("You tied" + tieInt++);


     }

        else
      {
             loseLabel.setText("You lose" + loseInt++);
     }


        }
    }



 public int determineWinner(String you, String opponent)
{

     if(you.equals("Rock") && (opponent.equals("Rock"))){
         //tieInt++;
         tieLabel.setText("You tied" + tieInt++);
         return tieInt++;
     }else if(you.equals("Rock") && (opponent.equals("Rock"))){
         //tieInt++;
         tieLabel.setText("You tied" + tieInt++);
        return tieInt++;
     }else if(you.equals("Scissors") && (opponent.equals("Scissors"))){
         //tieInt++;
         tieLabel.setText("You tied" + tieInt++);
         return tieInt++;
     }else if(you.equals("Rock") && (opponent.equals("Scissors"))){
         //winInt++;
         winLabel.setText("You Won" + winInt++);
         return winInt++; 
     }else if(you.equals("Paper") && (opponent.equals("Rock"))){
         //winInt++;
         //return 1;
         winLabel.setText("You Won" + winInt++);
         return winInt++;
     }else if(you.equals("Scissors") && (opponent.equals("Paper"))){
         //winInt++;
         //return 1;
         winLabel.setText("You Won" + winInt++);
         return winInt++;
     }else if(you.equals("Scissors") && (opponent.equals("Rock"))){
         //loseInt++;
         //return -1;
         loseLabel.setText("You lose" + loseInt++);
         return loseInt++;
     }else if(you.equals("Rock") && (opponent.equals("Paper"))){
         //loseInt++;
         //return -1;
         loseLabel.setText("You lose" + loseInt++);
         return loseInt++;
     }else 
         if(you.equals("Paper") && (opponent.equals("Scissors"))){
        //loseInt++;
         //return -1;
             loseLabel.setText("You lose" + loseInt++);
             return loseInt++;
     }
    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're shadowing your tieLabel variable by re-declaring it in the class. By doing this, the local variable declared in the constructor is initialized, but the field declared in the class remains null:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
   private JButton rockButton, paperButton, scissorsButton;

   // all these variables are null and remain null
   private JLabel userLabel, computerLabel, resultLabel, winLabel, tieLabel,
         loseLabel;

   // ...

   public GamePanel() {

      // ...

      // ***** shadowing vars here
      JButton rockButton = new JButton(rockButtonText);
      JButton paperButton = new JButton(paperButtonText);
      JButton scissorsButton = new JButton(scissorsButtonText);

      //...

      // *** and here
      JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User:");
      JLabel computerLabel = new JLabel("Computer:");
      JLabel winLabel = new JLabel("Win: " + winInt);
      JLabel tieLabel = new JLabel("Tie: " + tieInt);
      JLabel loseLabel = new JLabel("Lose:" + loseInt);
```

To avoid this, dont' redeclare. e.g.,

```
   public GamePanel() {

      // ...

      rockButton = new JButton(rockButtonText);
      paperButton = new JButton(paperButtonText);
      scissorsButton = new JButton(scissorsButtonText);

      //...

      userLabel = new JLabel("User:");
      computerLabel = new JLabel("Computer:");
      winLabel = new JLabel("Win: " + winInt);
      tieLabel = new JLabel("Tie: " + tieInt);
      loseLabel = new JLabel("Lose:" + loseInt);
```

Now the constructor will initialize the field that was declared in the class, and not initialize a local variable, and now the fields will not be null.

Comment: That makes sense but it still does not work :-/.  This is the error I get Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at GamePanel.determineWinner(GamePanel.java:176) and it continues like this javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: Wait nvm it works now.  But it isn't showing who played what next to user and computer with a "you won" or a "you lost" type thing :(.

Comment: @wwe9112: time to do some debugging. Either user your IDE's debugging capabilities or else use a bunch of println statements to figure out what state your variables are in as the program's running, and to thereby find our error.